# DataFrame Replace Not working on Multi Columns

Tags: dataframe

```
df_g1[["09-12-2013","14-09-2013","16-09-2013","18-09-2013","20-09-2013","22-09-2013"]].replace(["Removed","removed"],np.NaN,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parameter `inplace=True` in [**`pandas.Series.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) and re-assign your columns :

```
cols = ["09-12-2013","14-09-2013","16-09-2013","18-09-2013","20-09-2013","22-09-2013"]

df_g1[cols] = df_g1[cols].replace(["Removed","removed"],np.NaN)
```